# No such process at killing command after sometime

Tags: bash, time, timeout

I want to run an application from bash and kill it after sometime. I found [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/593029/140047):

```
xmessage "Hello World" & pidsave=$! sleep 10; kill $pidsave
```

But this is the result:

```
[4] 23034
[3]   Terminated              xmessage "Hello World"
bash: kill: (22985) - No such process
```

As you see, `xmessage` did not stopped and it's window remains. Of course [this](https://superuser.com/a/664938/140047) works:

```
your_command & sleep 20; kill $!
```

What is wrong in first command? And what is it's prefer in comparison whit second command?

Answer (score 0):

The process `xmessage` terminal already when you are running the `kill` command to kill it.

This can be seen here:

```
[3]   Terminated              xmessage "Hello World"
```

so there is no point `kill`-ing it afterwards.

---

**To answer why the window is still there:**

Many processes spawn another process, after that kills itself. This is happening in this case, the process you have spawned by running `xmessage` from terminal is spawning another one (the one with the window) and exits after that. The child remains running, and becomes an orphan as the parent died (`init` becomes it's new parent as `init` inherits all orphans).

Comment: But why does the 'xmessage' window remain?

Comment: Is there a way to detect those spawned processes and kill them?

Comment: @hasanghaforian Yes, get the list of children of `init` (PID 1). You can use any usual userspace tool available on your system e.g. `pgrep -lP 1`.